# This application requires the Windows Subsystem for Linux Optional Component

Tags: windows, homebrew, command-prompt

I was try to install brew in my cmd, and it cant so I need help for this

I allways use wsl for the port but its same

so please help me

[image: How to fix it]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to enable the Windows Features "Windows Subsystem for Linux" and "Virtual Machine Platform" to be able to successfully install and run the Ubuntu distro. This will require a restart.

[image: Windows Features]

I am running Windows 10 22H2 and installed WSL and Ubuntu via the Microsoft Store.

After enabling the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature, I got past the OP problem and needed to install a distro:

[image: WSL No Distributions]

After installing Ubuntu from the Store, I encountered this error when trying to execute it:

[image: Ubuntu Operation Failed]

After enabling the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature, Ubuntu was able to be installed as normal and I had a working distro.

[image: Ubuntu Installing]

Sources:

- https://superuser.com/a/1736464/705921
- https://linuxhint.com/enable-wsl-optional-component/